# Alfresco comment error on iPad for community 4.2.f

Tags: ipad, alfresco

When I use the Alfresco app for iPad in order to view sites on the Alfresco community 4.2.f, it shows the following error in red when trying to retrieve comments:

> "Unable to retrieve comments"

Everything else works good.

Is there any solution to fix it ?

Thanks!

Comment: Anything in your Alfresco log that sheds light on the cause?

Comment: File a JIRA at issues.alfresco.com. The mobility team is quite quick in responding and fixing stuff.

Comment: Hi @Gagravarr, nothing in the logs.

Comment: Can you look in the tomcat access logs, and see if the request for the comments came in? And if so, what http status code (eg 200, 500) the response got? That'll help track down if it's server side or client side that's the issue